# Visual Studio Code configure word break for text editor navigation

Tags: visual-studio-code

We tend to use kebab case for our naming in our FE app, but the ctrl arrow key navigation considers a dash a word break. Is there anyway to configure vscode so that ctrl + right/left behaves the same for both `FooBar` and `foo-bar`, i.e. considers both an entire word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vscode has native support for altering word breaks using the `editor.wordSeparators` setting.

> Characters that will be used as word separators when doing word related navigations or operations

Defaults to: `~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?`

You can simply remove the `-`:

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

Note: If you are using `cursorWordPartRight` keybind to navigate words partially, this setting will overrule it, meaning, you won't be able to step through the word partially (at that character), as the name implies.